# deploy QML-using, QBS-built Qt application to windows

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, qml, qbs

I have made an application in QtCreator

I use QML for the GUI, and I use QBS as the build system

I want to be able to deploy the application to windows (and maybe to Linux and MacOS, but right now, I'm only concerned with Windows)

I tried following the deployment tutorial for Qmake with a minimal example(using QBS to build the binary on windows, and with the MSVC2017 compiler, as of 2018-05-23 3:38 PM GMT-6 I've been trying to install MinGW with the Qt Maintenance tool for the last 6 hours, and it's still only at 5%, so I will try with MinGW once that finishes), but I have the following problem

using the Qt Quick Application - Swipe template, the release version with the MSVC2017 compiler, after using `windeployqt.exe --release --qmldir ../src example.exe` to get the dlls and other libraries

and trying to execute example.exe, I get a message saying

```
"Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment!"
```

in a cmd window, right before the actual application starts

and even if I try to disable that in the build step of the project, it doesn't get disabled

it still shows the cmd with the message, is there a way to completely make sure the build settings will work? am I missing a QtCreator configuration to make sure the settings I set actually do what they're intended? do I need to restart Qtcreator or Windows for them to work?

Update: still happens, even with MinGW

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that will be fixed in Creator 4.7. See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-20377.

Comment: oh, thanks, I wouldn't have thought it was an IDE bug, so, in theory, could I get around it if I used the command line to do the build/compilation?

Comment: Yes, add the following to the command line: modules.Qt.quick.qmlDebugging:false. It should also work in the "properties" line edit in the Qt Creator build step widget.

Comment: it did stop the Qml Debugging, but the command line window still opens